# Maximized windows hide behind wingpanel

Tags: wingpanel, window-management

Everytime I maximize a windows, a bit of the top hides behind the top bar on eOS Juno.

Screenshots:

**Normal behavior** (Not maximized, on Files)
[image: Normal behavior]

**Bug** (Files)
[image: Bug]

**Normal behavior** (Firefox)
[image]
**Bug** (Firefox)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/issues/130
Which I though I fixed with: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/198
Looks like it hasn't been released yet: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/releases

Update: The fix is included in the latest version `2.2.3`.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having that bug a while ago. Updating solved it.
For those that can't see the difference, the top bar is a bit cropped when the window is maximized.

Comment: I have updated everything I could update, and the problem persists..